# Samsung 32" LCD TV as PC Monitor, resolution problems

Tags: linux, tv, nvidia-graphics-card, xrandr

I have a Samsung LE32C450 TV connected to my Nvidia 7300LE via the VGA connector.
I managed to obtain 1360x768 resolution (after some work, NVidia driver, Nvidia-settings, xrandr, cursing to every known god, etc..), but on the TV I don't see the 'complete' figure.

I have some unused space to the left (like if the screen is 'moved to the right'), and the rightmost part of the screen is off the TV (but the mouse pointer 'can go there').

It's really a weird situation.

Where do I have to look/read/modify/hack/curse?

PS: I'm running Debian.

I prefer to stick with Nvidia proprietary drivers (sometimes I need OpenGL acceleration). Now I setup 1024x768 4:3 and this resolution is working, but if it's possible to obtain the native resolution of the TV panel (1360x768 16:9) will be better.

The TV connection is an emergency, because I need my PC for work, and I have problems with the PC monitor, so I connected my TV.

Comment: What do nv and nouveau have to say about it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please consider properly [registering](http://superuser.com/users/login) an account. While your "unregistered account" is kept in a browser cookie, you seem to have lost that (or switched computers) and cannot edit your own question or respond properly to comments and answers.

Comment: unfortunatly you may be out of luck there.  nvidia seems to have gotten rid of their monitor ajustments in their drivers. I used to be able to adjust about every thing but now not so especially in linux drivers.  you may be able to get away with adjusting timings by hand but it will be ugly.